# VSTS: Deploy Azure SQL DACPAC throws an error

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-devops, ms-release-management

I am trying to setup a Release on VSTS for an Azure SQL database using the 'Deploy Azure SQL DACPAC'. I get the following error (with `system.debug = true`)

```
2016-08-09T06:23:08.4767615Z Publishing to database 'DBName' on server 'DBServer'. 
2016-08-09T06:23:08.6821649Z Initializing deployment (Start) 
2016-08-09T06:23:24.7312223Z Initializing deployment (Failed) 
2016-08-09T06:23:24.7684904Z ##[debug]System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: * Could not deploy package. 
2016-08-09T06:23:24.7794888Z ##[debug][Azure RDFE Call] Deleting firewall rule 7d14da9b-4c86-4ed6-a3f3-d238a3143c39 on azure database server: DBServer 
2016-08-09T06:23:25.9730592Z ##[debug][Azure RDFE Call] Firewall rule 7d14da9b-4c86-4ed6-a3f3-d238a3143c39 deleted on azure database server: DBServer 
2016-08-09T06:23:25.9840576Z ##[error]System.Management.Automation.ParentContainsErrorRecordException: * Could not deploy package.
```

Following is the publish profile -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <IncludeCompositeObjects>True</IncludeCompositeObjects>
    <TargetDatabaseName>SocialRecruiting</TargetDatabaseName>
    <DeployScriptFileName>Database.sql</DeployScriptFileName>
    <TargetConnectionString>Data Source=DBServer;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=username;Pooling=False</TargetConnectionString>
    <ProfileVersionNumber>1</ProfileVersionNumber>
    <ScriptDatabaseOptions>True</ScriptDatabaseOptions>
    <BlockOnPossibleDataLoss>True</BlockOnPossibleDataLoss>
    <CreateNewDatabase>False</CreateNewDatabase>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I read a couple of similar posts on this, one here and one on another forum. They suggested adding the IP range manually (`0.0.0.0` to `255.255.255.255`) and using friendly server name instead of FQDN but that did not work.
I am able to publish it manually through Visual Studio without any problems.

**EDIT**
I tried the suggestions from the following posts already
[VSTS: Deploy Azure SQL DACPAC Release Management throwing an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38224043/vsts-deploy-azure-sql-dacpac-release-management-throwing-an-error)
[Azure SQL DACPAC task keeps failing](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/2123)

**EDIT - full DACPAC log** 
http://pastebin.com/bWvTi5Vx

Comment: Can you share your build definition settings?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the settings for "Deploy Azure SQL DACPAC" task.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/Snt3x  
DACPAC file - $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Folder/Drop/Database/bin/Output/Database.dacpac  
Publish Profile - $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Folder/Drop/Database/CloudDBName.publish.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this with the help of a colleague's friend. The database that was being updated had a table with a column set as NULL and the DACPAC had the create script for the table with column as NOT NULL which caused the error. I altered the existing table to make the column NOT NULL and the release worked.

Comment: You can mark it as answer so that other people has the same issue could see this.

Comment: I will do that, once I can. I can't mark my own answer until 24 hours have passed after posting this.